# How to re-implement Django Authentication middleware

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt, middleware

Current

```py
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
```

Is logging in the user and such but using different JWT token from different generated sources (ex apple google github) will not work with this one because it's accepting only and only the one from

```py
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES": [
        "graphql_auth.mutations.Register",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken",
    ],
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True,
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=365),
    "JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=365),
}
```

I've already implemented a custom middleware "CustomAuthenticationMiddleware" and It works fine but I need to remove the already existing auth middleware and I get this error

```bash
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (admin.E408) 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
```